# Google Drive won't play my videos after upgrading to windows 10

Tags: windows-10, video, vlc-media-player, google-drive, mp4

I finally got around to upgrading to windows 10 on my PCs. But now my videos that I had stored in Google Drive won't play. They're MP4. So then I tried using VLC media player because that was recommended to me, but either it doesn't work with that or i just can't figure out how to get it to work. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Ideas? I've got a couple: 1. You didn't use the real VLC Media Player. Go to the official Website, and download it [here](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html). 2. You didn't download the video correctly. Try re-downloading 3. Try playing the video on a browser to see if its actually a system issue. What version of windows are you using? I'll edit if I can think of anything else.

Comment: Are you still able to play those videos on another computer not running Windows 10?  What about if you copy a video to a flash drive, confirm it doesn't play on the Windows 10 computer from the flash drive, and try playing it from another computer?

Comment: The only videos that don't play are my videos I store in Google Drive. All other vids play no problem. But it's when I upgraded to Windows 10 that my vids in Drive stopped working. I still have not been able to get them to play.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Windows App (store) version of VLC or the desktop application?  I haven't tested this personally but that might make a difference.  The App version doesn't play DVDs like the desktop version does so you may need to install both.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/vlc/9nblggh4vvnh

Comment: Thanks. I'll try out these options. It actually plays videos fine, it only does not play videos that I have stored in Google Drive anymore.